# Need to travel to the USA by ship from Europe

Tags: usa, europe

I need to travel to the USA (east coast preferably) leaving in April and getting there about the first week of May at the latest. Would exclude cargo or freighter ship crossings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [France to USA by ship](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96290/france-to-usa-by-ship)

Comment: Unless you are willing to book freighter passage, your options are practically non-existent.  Even Queen Mary 2 doesn't begin here westbound passages until mid May and all other ships are transiting to Europe for the summer season.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Cunard - from Southampton to New York ....  easy and relatively cheap (< 1300 pounds).

Comment: Cunard's website says the next ship leaves 10th May and arrives 17th May. A bit later tan requested, but may be OK.